# How to find when a request had started and when it got ended in scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy, throughput

I am trying to measure the throughput of the system in scrapy and I am trying to find when the HTTP request was fired and when it was completed completed in scrapy.

Any directions to find a solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: This is a very broad question.. are you looking to determine if your parsing power is limiting vs your download speed? I'd take a quick tour of scrapy's [architecture overview](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html) and come back with something more specific..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use custom middleware:

```
class MeasureMiddleware:
    requests = []

    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        # store the time and url of every outgoing request
        self.requests.append((request.url, datetime.now()))

    def process_response(self, request, response, spider):
        # for everyone response check if one of tracked requests cameback
        # if so, print start time and current time
        filtered_requests = []
        # go through tracked requests and check whether any of them match current url
        for request in self.requests:
            url, start_date = request
            if url == request.url:
                logging.info(f'request {url} {start_date} - {datetime.now()}')
            else:
                filtered_requests.append(request)
        self.requests = filtered_requests
```

Then activate the downloader middleware

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'myproject.middlewares.MeasureMiddleware': 543,
}
```

It's worth noting that due to async nature of scrapy it won't be ms accurate but it should be accurate enough to give a generic overview.